# How to do keyword search in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to do a keyword search.  I'm receiving a string and I need to search the database for keywords contained in that string.

So if I have a string "Watercolor Paintings" it would bring back keyword records from the database for "watercolor" and "painting".  How do I perform this query?  Is there a contains query or a substring query that will work?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: try this `Model.where("title like ?", "%#{keyword}%")`

Comment: To avoid sql-injection try this `Model.where('title LIKE ?', '%' + keyword + '%')`

Comment: Doesn't that give me the reverse?  I want something like Model.where('keyword is in ?', "Watercolor Paintings")

Comment: keyword is my database column.  I want the records back that are found in the search string

Comment: by keyword i mean `Watercolor Paintings` which is the keyword you want to search. I don't know your table and field names

Comment: So the query "keyword like %Watercolor Paintings%" would give me back both records?  The record for "watercolor" and the record for "paintings"?  Or do I have to search through each word in the search string individually?

Comment: `Model.where('keyword LIKE ?', '%' + "Watercolor Paintings" + '%')` should give as many records which have any of the two words

Comment: I'll test it out when I get the rest of this setup.  Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it after I test it?

Comment: Just to extend Sontya's comment, you may find it more useful to break the search terms into words by whitespace.  For instance if you search for "Watercolor Paintings", it's a quoted string (and thus ANDs the words in that order) but if you break the submitted search string down and use something like `Model.where('keyword REGEXP "watercolor|paintings"'), you may find ORing the words in any order this way instead offers a more versatile search experience (a la google).

Comment: Sounds like you should read up on mysql's full text search capabilities

Comment: Full Text seems to do the trick.